# Maps of presheaves. Aren't they just transpositions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a presheaf on $X$, let $U$ have open cover $\{U_i\}$ and define three maps:

$$\rho:\mathcal{F}(U)\to \prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{F}(U_i),\quad s\mapsto(s|_{U_i})_i$$
$$\sigma:\prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{F}(U_i)\to \prod_{(i,j)\in I^2}\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j),\quad (s_i)_i\mapsto (s_i|_{U_i\cap U_j})_{(i,j)}$$
$$\sigma':\prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{F}(U_i)\to \prod_{(i,j)\in I^2}\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j),\quad (s_i)_i\mapsto (s_j|_{U_i\cap U_j})_{(i,j)}$$

I wanted to play with this to find out what was going on with $\sigma,\sigma'$ so the smallest example is $U=U_1\cup U_2$.

Then $\rho(s)=(s|_{U_1},s|_{U_2})=(s_1,s_2)$ (latter is just fixing a notation)

Then $\sigma(s_1,s_2)=(s_1,s_1|_{U_2},s_2|_{U_1},s_2)$ and $\sigma'(s_1,s_2)=(s_1,s_2|_{U_1},s_1|_{U_2},s_2)$ Right?

Aren't the image of $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ always just transpositions of one another?

---

Context: Algebraic Geometry I - Schemes with examples and exercises - Gortz:

He defines a presheaf to be a sheaf if the following sequence is exact:

$$\mathcal{F}(U)\stackrel{\rho}{\to}\prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{F}(U_i)\stackrel{\stackrel{\sigma}{\rightrightarrows}}{\sigma'}\prod_{(i,j)\in I^2} \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)$$

The ordering on $I^2$ that I gave I just picked myself. He says this exactness means that the image of $\rho$ is the set of elements $(s_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $\sigma((s_i)_i)=\sigma'((s_i)_i)$

> If these **are** equal up to ordering, why would he mention this?(*this* being that exactness gives: $\sigma((s_i)_i)=\sigma'((s_i)_i)$)

Comment: Of what are you taking the product in the second and third lines? Should it be $\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)$? Also, writing 
$$\sigma(s_1,s_2)=(s_1,s_1|_{U_2},s_2|_{U_1},s_2)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\sigma'(s_1,s_2)=(s_1,s_2|_{U_1},s_1|_{U_2},s_2),$$
assumes an ordering on the product over $I^2$. If you don't assume an arbitrary ordering on the products then it is clear that the maps $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are in fact the same.

Comment: @Servaes Oops oops oops!

Comment: @Servaes I added context

Comment: Now exactness means that $(s|_{U_i})|_{U_j}=(s|_{U_j})|_{U_i}$ for all $i,j\in I$. For restriction of maps this is obvious, but the maps $\mathcal{F}(U_i)\ \longrightarrow\ \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)$ can be anything, and in general it needn't be the case that these two are the same.

Comment: The notation in the definition is a little cumbersome, I am afraid. One could have, say, defined a total order on $I$, and say that the $(s_i)$ agree on pairwise intersections $U_i \cap U_j$ for all $i,j \in I$, $i<j$. Anyway, I think it should be clear by now, thanks to Servaes's comments.

Comment: I don't understand what Servaes's comments means. The maps $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are **not** the same, and the ordering of $I^2$ has nothing to do with the story. You wrote correctly the maps, and they indeed differ by some permutation on the coordinates. But the equality $\sigma(s_i)_i=\sigma'(s_i)_i$ is not always true. There are plenty of redundant informations, the only one interesting in the case of 2 open subsets is $s_1|_{U_2}=s_2|_{U_1}$ (or better perhaps : $s_1|_{U_1\cap U_2}=s_2|_{U_1\cap U_2}$). It just mean that $s_1$ and $s_2$ agree on the intersection $U_1\cap U_2$.

Comment: Now exactness of the sequence mean the following : $\sigma(s_i)_i=\sigma'(s_i)_i$ iff $(s_i)_i$ is of the form $(s|_{U_i})_i$. Using what we said previously, exactness of the sequence means $(s_i)_i$ agree on pairwise intersection $U_i\cap U_j$ iff $(s_i)$ is of the form $(s|_{U_i})$ which is exactly the sheaf condition.

Comment: @Roland I hadn't realised that there seems to be some confusion, perhaps by the notation introduced. In the question $s_1$ and $s_2$ are *defined* as $s_1:=s|_{U_1}$ and $s_2:=s|_{U_2}$ for some $s\in\mathcal{F}(U)$. I think your comment actually answers the question behind the question. And indeed the maps $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ aren't the same, my attention got stuck at the typo's in their definitions.

Comment: @Servaes Ah I see ! The line $\rho(s)=(s|_{U_1},s|_{U_2})=(s_1,s_2)$ in the OP is indeed confusing. The last equality should not be there.